# Blurry sprite after scaling in Android Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

The title is self explanatory but this my particular context. I need a sprite that has a brown rectangle as textureRegion (600x150) Like it is a simple image i thoght that i could use a 20x5 version of the image and then after ataching is to the sprite `sprite.setScale(30);`
 But when running the borders are not well defined.

Why have this happened and whats the right way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Why dont you store full resolution texture? Why do you need to scale it? Because of memory needed? 2. If it is just a rectangle why dont you use Rectangle class?

Comment: 1- Yes because of memory  2-I know i could use a rectangle in this case but this is one example, I got a ton of .png reduced to minimize memory that i want to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Since your graphics is not vector based, of course the sprite will be blurry if you scaling it up. You have to use svg graphics or full resolution texture.

Alternatively you can use different texture folders for different dpi, this is the method i'm using in my games. This way large resolution phones/tablets using hd textures and old or small phones using lower resolution textures.

Comment: But why does it become blurry?. I mean in the example i use a rectangle image, How could it become blurry if is just multiplying  the current pixels